# How to pass through to a base value in a generic wrapper struct?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, wrapper, swift-protocols

Given a generic wrapper struct in the following form:

```swift
struct Observable<Base> {
    var base: Base
}
```

How can I pass through functionality that is applied to a value of type `Observable` to the inner `Base`? This can rather easily be done, for instance, with the `Equatable` protocol by writing an extension, declaring the requirements `func ==` and just calling through to an existing conformance of `Base` to `Equatable`, like this:

```swift
extension Observable: Equatable where Base: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Observable<Base>, rhs: Observable<Base>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.base == rhs.base
    }
}
```

How could I do the same for *pattern matching*, e.g. so that I can `switch`, for example, on a value of type `Observable<String?>` directly, just like I would do if it wasn't wrapped in `Observable`? An example I'd like to solve and see working would be:

```swift
enum Availability {
    case available
    case notAvailable
}

let observableDescription = Observable<Availability>(.notAvailable)

switch observableDescription {
    case .available: // …
    case .notAvailable: // …
}
```

**Bonus question:** Is it possible to provide conformance to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` to the generic type `Observable` so that I can write `let collection: Observable<[Int]> = []`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two structs for two questions

### [Expression Pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID426)

`Equatable` actually have [`~=(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539154) as a requirement:

```
extension Observable: Equatable where Base: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Observable<Base>, rhs: Observable<Base>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.base == rhs.base
    }

    static func ~= (pattern: Base, value: Self) -> Bool {
        pattern ~= value.base
    }
}
```

and now you can just do :

```
let observableDescription = Observable<Availability>(base: .notAvailable)
switch observableDescription {
case .available:
    print("available")
case .notAvailable:
    print("notAvailable") // "notAvailable\n"
default:
    print("default")
}
```

#### [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral)

For this one you will need an base array:

```
struct ObservableSequence<Base>: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where Base: Sequence {
    var base: [Base.Element]
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Base.Element...) {
        base = Array(elements)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let emptyCollection: ObservableSequence<[Int]> = []
print(emptyCollection.base) // "[]\n"
let collection: ObservableSequence<[Double]> = [1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0]
print(collection.base) // "[1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0]\n"
```